# What are best algorithms/patterns to read xml files using [java] sax?

Tags: java, xml, algorithm, design-patterns

Let's suppose we have the following xml

```
<books>
   <book>
      <id>...</id>  
      <title>...</title>
      <references>
         <book>
           <id>...</id>  
           <title>...</title>
         </book>
      </references>            
      <authors>
         <author>
           <id>...</id>
           <name>...</name>
            <written-books>
              <book>
              <id>...</id>  
              <title>...</title>
              </book>
            </written-books>
         </author>
      </authors>
   <book>
</books>
```

What I do now is to use booleans to find out in what sections we are (book,references,authors,written-books). I do this on starte/end element event ,After that on characters event I check

```
if (qName.equals("id"){
   if (writtenBooks){
   }else if (authors){
   }else if (references){
   }else{
   }
}else if ("title")...
```

But it doesn't seem to be too elegant. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding what you have to do is read the XML and then process it. (Check the existence of the elements etc.) You can use Apache Axiom to read xml files and get the content easily. Then you can process it as you want.I will put a example code segment to get the content of the xml file using AXIOM.

```
    //read the xml file
    StAXOMBuilder builder = new StAXOMBuilder(xmlStreamReader);
    OMElement endPointElem = builder.getDocumentElement();


   // go though the xml elemetns and do whatever you want
    Iterator children = endPointElem.getChildElements();
    while (children.hasNext()) {
    ........................
    .......
    }
```

For more details [This post will helpful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470925/how-should-i-read-xml-element-from-axiom)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I think my problem was in using sax instead of stax.